# The task of my tag stay in scheduled mode

Tags: airflow

I have the following dag declaration:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from pymongo import MongoClient

from time import sleep

import pendulum
import random

default_args = {
    'owner': 'aiirflow',
    'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 14, 25),
    'retries': 1
}

dag = DAG('mongodb_dag', description="Ingest simple document into mongoDB", schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 14, 25, tz="Europe/Paris"))

def create_document():
    # Connexion à la base de données MongoDB
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://:27017/admin')
    db = client.airflowTestDB

    # Insertion du document initial
    document = {"documentId": 0}
    result = db.airflowExtractCollection.insert_one(document)
    print("Wrote to db " + str(result))
    sleep(15)

def transform_document():
    # Connexion à la base de données MongoDB
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://:27017/admin')
    db = client.airflowTestDB

    # Lecture du document initial
    document = db.airflowExtractCollection.find_one({"documentId": 0})

    print("Read from db " + str(document))

    # Modification du document
    document["documentId"] = random.randint(1, 1000000)

    # Insertion du document transformé dans la nouvelle collection
    result = db.airflowTransformedExtract.insert_one(document)
    print("Wrote to db " + str(result))
    sleep(15)

task_create_document = PythonOperator(
    task_id='create_document',
    python_callable=create_document,
    dag=dag,
)

task_transform_document = PythonOperator(
    task_id='transform_document',
    python_callable=transform_document,
    dag=dag,
)

task_create_document >> task_transform_document
```

The issue is that the task stays in scheduled state:

[image]

I don't understand why because I have no error anywhere/

I assumed the issue came from the airflow displayed time and the one on the actual server which is why I used pendulum to set it to a proper time. I also ensured that the time on interface was the same.

Yet nothing runs.

The only way I could run it was manual.

What could be the issue ?

EDIT: I actually noticed that it's the case even for the example dag provide by airflow such as the example_branch_dop_operator_v3:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_python_dop_operator_3.py

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you are using the start_date as today, the same date you are running the pipeline. I remember when I started using Airflow I had the same problem and since then I started to use the start_date as a day before, so in your case 27/04. You can try and see if works

Comment: Did you have to put the catchup parameter ?

Comment: There is no need, it worked?

Comment: It did not. I think that I just don't have enough ressource and the scheduler don't do his job. I don't know

Comment: It finally did, the issue I had was because one of my celery worker could not read the database due to missconfiguration.